# Ubuntu 14.10 frozen at startup screen

Tags: 14.04, startup, vmware-fusion

After having installed updates (a popup appeared asking for automatic updates to be installed), I rebooted and after typing the password, the screen was frozen and the SO GUI wasn't loading. I restarted many times, I tried to load a previous version of the kernel, and I also tried to run the commands apt-get update and apt-get dist-update from the shell prompt in recovery mode, but the SO won't boot.

[image]

Comment: I updated today and it broke Parallels. I get a full login, but if I launch an app, no windows display. Clicking the gear menu on the top right causes flashing and no window. It appears that it recognized the click, because the bar changes, and you can click elsewhere, and recover the bar. But the window itself does not show. The toolbar on the left can respond to clicks, dim, etc, but no windows produced. Turning off Parallels 3D acceleration fixes the problem. OSX 10.9.5
Parallels 10.1.1

Comment: So sorry you have had this experience.  As you can see, someone else with this problem has posted an answer, which admittedly is no answer at all, but at least reflects a similar problem.  If we can only find what the two of you have in common, it may solve problems for everyone else, so please describe your system and be especially specific about such things as whether you are using the 32 or 64 bit versions of Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: It's the 32-bit version. The 3D acceleration was already disabled, however I tried to add this line in the vmx file: "mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = FALSE". It still doesn't boot. I see the mouse icon, but it seems like the clicks are not recognized.